# Flask - CGI - cant find .htaccess

Tags: python, flask

according to the Flask documentation:
http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/deploying/cgi/

I should change the .httaccess file, but i cant find it..

this is the cgi file path:
/home/trafficzon/py.trafficzone.online/cgi-bin/flask.cgi

also, how can i see the log when running cgi ?

Comment: This is a file that you'll need to create

Comment: in this path?
home/trafficzon/py.trafficzone.online/

Comment: If that's were you're serving the CGI, the probably yes, but it depends on how your Apache is configured. This is a question for whoever set up the Apache you're using. If it's you, consult the Apache docs for enabling `.htaccess`. (You'll know you're in the right place when there's mention of `AllowOverride`.)

Comment: thanks it was there! 
but now i get this error:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55715990/apache-no-matching-directoryindex-path-is-changing-to-public-html

Comment: Post a new question for that